# Sitecore sheerresponse, multiple inputfields

Tags: c#, sitecore

I'm extending one the sitecore fields ( TreelistEx )
I've already found how i can ask the user for a single input(field).

```
            SheerResponse.Input("Enter the name of the new item:",
                "New Item Default Name",
                Settings.ItemNameValidation,
                Translate.Text("'$Input' is not a valid name."),
                Settings.MaxItemNameLength);
```

But i would like to ask the user for 3 things ( firstname, lastname, phonenumber  ). Is there any way to achieve this ?

( The solution wouldn't have to use a Sheerresponse )

Edit: I'm using Sitecore 8 Update 2